# Ubuntu 19.04 can't get 2560x1600 on HP L3065 display w/ HDMI to DVI adapter; Windows can

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

I recently got this old HP L3065 30" 2560x1600 monitor that only takes DVI inputs.  I purchased [this cheap cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014I8UU2W) to connect the monitor to my PC.  When Iconnected, it works fine in Windows 10.

However, Ubuntu 19.04 shows the only supported resolution is 1280x800.  I tried adding a 2560x1600 resolution using `xrandr` but I either got `xrandr: cannot find mode "2560x1600"` when trying to get the mode or, using a custom definition I found online:

```
$ xrandr --newmode "2560x1600_60.00"  348.50  2560 2760 3032 3504  1600 1603 1609 1658 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --mode 2560x1600_60.00
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
```

Most of the forums I've visited say I need a dual-link DVI to DisplayPort cable, but the ones that support 2560x1600 are over $100;  I'd like to not spend that on a cable, if I can find another solution.

I feel like there must be a software solution to this since Windows is interfacing perfectly fine with the monitor.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.